# OpenLayers Problem | Unable to zoom Layer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am trying basic examples of OpenLayers with my own Geoserver. When I tried to replace WMS with own local WMS path, I am unable to zoom layer after a specific scale.

```
var map;


function init(){
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {});
            var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(


        'OpenLayers WMS',
        'http:/localhost:7000/geoserver/test/wms',
        {layers: 'test:builtup'},
        {}
    );


    map.addLayer(wms);
    if(!map.getCenter()){
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
}
```

Please help me with possible error.

[image: This is the max scale]

Comment: At first I thought it was a scope with wms but on second thought I do not think so , but make var wms global to be sure. Also grab a developer tool like firefox/firebug and see if the layer is actually added to the map. I take it the above image is from geoserver and not from your web page.

Comment: Add the projection to your map options.

Comment: This is occurring because of zoomlevels, which are upto 16 by default. When my map loads, that shows a smaller map and i have to zoom in. The picture I have attached, is on max zoom and i am unable to zoom in more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you set a projection and the number of zoom levels in your map options you will be able to zoom in closer.

```
var options = {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913'),
    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    units: 'm', 
    //resolutions: [ 152.87405654907226, 76.43702827453613, ...],
    numZoomLevels: 20,
    //maxResolution: 152.87405654907226,
    controls: [ ]
};

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',options);
```